# Objective-C Memory Leak (VideoTooplbox, MediaToolBox,AVFoundation)

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I have a Memory Leak problem. I think this code does not work correctly?

The UseCase is:
Take a fullscreen image (Portrait) and save in UIImageview.

Problem: taken image was not equal the saved image. After saving, the rotation of the image was landscape in my UIImageview.

Solution: change image orientation (see. removeRotationForImage)

New Problem: Sometimes the view freeze if I take image and press on the "use picture" button. And Memory Leaks.

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

```
{    

    -(IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender{

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];   
}

{

    -(UIImage *)removeRotationForImage:(UIImage*)image {

    if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return image;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, image.scale);
    [image drawInRect:(CGRect){0, 0, image.size}];
    UIImage *normalizedImage =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return normalizedImage;

}

{

    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UIImage *imageWithCorrectOrientation = [self removeRotationForImage:chosenImage];
    ..
    ..
    ..
}
```

Comment: You could try to limit the number of images you have stored in memory. For example when you create the variable imageWithCorrectOrientation  there are then 2 large images in memory. both imageWithCorrectOrientation and chosenImage.

You could try this instead:

NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    chosenImage  = [self removeRotationForImage:chosenImage];

Comment: i have find out the error. I have use "UIImagePNGRepresentation" and  the size of the taken images was >10MB.... Now i use UIImageJPEGRepresentation and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

We are also facing similar problem. I have created thread @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177221/iphone-app-crashes-randomly-while-capturing-more-than-100-photos-uiimagepickerco link, too. Kindly provide your view if its resolved for you.